# Apostrophe Placement

Tags: apostrophe

Please can you help.  Here is my sentence:

For best results, you’d be sensible to ensure they’re songs which are suitable for your voices current skill level.

Where would you place the  apostrophe on the word ‘voices’

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since the skill level belongs to your voice then the sentence should be

> For best results, you’d be sensible to ensure they’re songs which are suitable for your voice's current skill level.

However, it seems a clumsy phrasing and might be better as

> For best results, you should ensure they’re songs which are suitable for your voice's current skill level.